# Simplify a batch of git commands

Tags: git

When I want to merge one branch to another I use to do the following(in this example master to custom):

```
git checkout master && git pull && git checkout custom && git merge master
```

Can somebody suggest how to simplify this?

Thanks, Bogdan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git checkout custom && git pull origin master`

Comment: Assuming, of course, that the local branch *master* was pulling from remote branch *master* on the remote *origin*. This is likely to be the case if the local repository was a simple clone of a repository with a *master* branch as its HEAD, but it is not always true.

Comment: This does something different to the recipe in the original question. In the original question origin's master is merged into the local master and the the result of that merge is merged into custom. These only do the same thing if the first merge was a fast-forward. Also this sequence doesn't update the local master branch.

Answer (score 2):

It can not be simplified in the general case. Both the merge and the pull (which uses either a merge or a rebase) might need a working tree to allow the user to resolve potential conflicts.

There may be some simplifying assumptions that you can make though.

If your local *master* never has any local changes (i.e. every pull into your local *master* will always be a “fast-forward” update; possibly because the only reason you have a local *master* is because *git clone* automatically made one for you), then you can probably just ignore your local *master* and re-configure your local *custom* to pull from the same upstream that your local *master* uses.

```
# copy "upstream" config from 'master' to 'custom'
for o in remote merge rebase mergeoptions; do
    v="$(git config branch.master."$o")" && 
      git config branch.custom."$o" "$v"
done
```

Then, to merge the upstream into *custom* just do `git checkout custom && git pull`.

Alternatively, you could work directly on your local *master* (move your *custom* commits to *master* with `git checkout master && git reset --hard custom`, then you could abandon or delete *custom*).

Answer (score -1):

use a shell script